# Modelling current to remain in particular range for fixed simulation time

Tags: digital-logic, current, verilog, system-verilog, encoding

I am a novice in SystemVerilog. I wish to know how to model a 8-bit signal X to attain four levels for certain ranges of time. For example,let the legal values of X be from 40 to 80(40 < X < 80)

1. 40 - X - 50  for 70% of simulation time   : State 1
2. 50 - X - 60  for 10% of simulation time   : State 2
3. 60 - X - 70  for 10% of simulation time   : State 3
4. 70 - X - 80  for 10% of simulation time   : State 4

Comment: It's really unclear what it is you want to do here.

Comment: Still not clear what you're getting at.  Do you want to stay in state 1 for 7 clock cycles, then go to state 2 for 1 clock cycle, then 3 for 1 cycle, then 4 for 1 cycle, then repeat?  Or do you want to do a random walk that spends 70% of the time in state 1 and 10% of the time in each of the other 3?  Something else entirely?

Comment: @alex I need a random walk. I have removed the clocks tag.

Comment: @alex, removing meta comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a random number generator to generate a random number and then assign it to a state based on its value.

For example, if I generate a random number between 1 and 100, then if it's below 70, it goes to state 1, below 80 goes to state 2, below 90 goes to state three, and below 100 goes to state 4.

I'm going to use the SV built-in random function in this example, but you can use any random number generator that you'd like for synthesis.

Here's a primitive example:

```
module tb;

   reg clk = 0;
   reg rst;


   // Clock definition
   localparam       clk_period = 10000; // 100 Mhz
   always begin
      clk   = #(clk_period/2) ~clk;
   end 

   // reset definition
   initial begin 
      rst = 1;
      #(25*clk_period);  
      @(posedge clk);      
      rst = 0;
   end


   enum      {STATE_1,STATE_2,STATE_3,STATE_4} state;
   reg [7:0] random_num;

   always@(posedge clk) begin
      if (rst == 1) begin
         random_num <= $random % 50 + 50;
         state <= STATE_1;
      end
      else begin
         random_num <= $random % 50 + 50;

         if (random_num < 70)
           state <= STATE_1;
         else if  (random_num < 80)
           state <= STATE_2;
         else if  (random_num < 90)
           state <= STATE_3;
         else if  (random_num < 100)
           state <= STATE_4;

      end
   end

endmodule
```

Comment: @Stacey-rst not declared.

Comment: this isn't a complete example, it would need to be integrated into an existing testbench.

Comment: agreed. We must also take into consideration whether rst can be active-high or active-low. Just suggesting.

Comment: Added in complete testbench code and switched to using $random because $urandom isn't simulatable by xilinx yet.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to implement this is to use $random and compare to four thresholds.  $random will return a random 32-bit integer from 0 to 2^32-1, so just segment this into four chunks, see which one the result falls in to, and set your signal accordingly.  Evaluate this whenever you want the signal level to change - every clock cycle or n clock cycles, or on a delay that's independent of the clock.